# Using Apply to create a new dataframe columns based on existing columns

Tags: python, function, apply

```
def calc():
  return df2['Strike'] + df2['Bid']

df2['new'] = df2.apply(calc)
```

```
Error --->
df2['new'] = df2.apply(calc)

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 21, placement implies 1
```

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title. Format codea and error. Show example data which makes problem.

Comment: `apply()` runs function for every row separatelly and you you should use `def calc(row): row['strike'] + row['Bid']` . OR you should run it without `apply` - `df2['new'] = df2['Strike'] + df2['Bid']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apply()` runs function for every `row` (or `column`) separatelly and you should use

```
def calc(row): 
    return row['Strike'] + row['Bid']

df2['new'] = df2.apply(calc, axis=1)  # `axis=1` for `rows`
```

It gets one `row` as argument and it returns one `row` as result.
In your code you return `df2` which can mean all 21 rows at once.

---

But for your example you could run it without `apply`

```
df2['new'] = df2['Strike'] + df2['Bid']
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Strike': [1,2,3], 
    'Bid': [4,5,6], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# ---

df['new'] = df['Strike'] + df['Bid']

# ---

def calc(row):
    return row['Strike'] + row['Bid']

df['new_apply'] = df.apply(calc, axis=1)  

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Strike  Bid  new  new_apply
0       1    4    5          5
1       2    5    7          7
2       3    6    9          9
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for your time and help.

Comment: if it helps then you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.